# need to pass in data in a get request in angulalr

Tags: angular, http, get

I've got a model a controller and a Angular component, i'll display below:

In the model:

```
videosModel.get = function(skip, limit){
    var results = q.defer();

    skip = parseInt(skip) || 0;
    limit = parseInt(limit) || 10;

    Video.find(function(err, dbVideo) {
        if (err){
            results.reject(err);
        } 

        results.resolve(dbVideo);
    }).skip(skip).limit(limit);

    return results.promise;

}
```

In the controller:

```
videos.get = function (req, res) {

    var skip = req.query.skip;
    var limit = req.query.limit;

    var videosData = videoModel.get(skip, limit);
    videosData.then(function(data){
        var response = {};
        response.status='success';
        response.data=data;
        res.send(response);
    }, function(err){
        res.send(err);
    });

};
```

And the Angular:

```
  getvideos(){
        var str = 'http://localhost:27017/videos?sessionId='+ this.sessionId;
        this.http.get(str).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

In the model, there are two variables in the get function, "skip" and "limit" and I need to pass paramemters into those.

The context is that in the database there are 50 videos but we must only display 10 at a time, so the http calls only bring in 10 videos at a time, thus the parameters will increment by 10 after each call.  But right now I am not passing in any parameters.

skip = parseInt(skip) || 0;

As you see, the parameter is not necessary because we have an or operator, so right now in my current http angular code, it is defaulting to the 0, but I would like this skip variable to choose instead the parseInt(skip), but I need to pass in a variable to do this.

Comment: its a angularjs application write, means angular 1.x?

Comment: Angular4, meanings Angular2 or Angular, means NOT Angularjs and NOT Angular1